# How to handle a role swap when using a Spring JPA persistent entity manager?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-data-jpa

I am working on an application that will be using a persistent Spring JPA entitymanager. Our production database is on two servers that occasionally swap roles as to which one is live and which one is the backup. Will the entitymanager have any problems with the role swap? If so, what is the best way to handle it?

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Repository
public class CarolJpaDao
{
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
```

pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity manager does not know about the servers, the connection does. As long as the connection given to the entity manager "points" to the correct database, it would be ok. If the change of database is so that it becomes unavailable in the middle of a transaction, that could cause problems.

You could implement a connection datasource that "knows" witch server is up and provides the correct connections. There could be a configuration on the database to handle the role swap transparently too. It will depend on your setup.